# Can Javascript access WCF services protected by a certificate?

Tags: javascript, wcf, web-services, rest, certificate

I'd like to use Javascript to access a WCF-based web service that is protected by a certificate.

Assuming that I can generate and store the private key in protected storage, is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can handle certificates with javascript. If the user has accepted a certificate from a server, you may access that one though.

Comment: @Bergi I'm open to either implicit certificate validation (HTTP level as you describe) or explicit with the private key stored in a local trusted store (HTML5 storage, etc)